# Elm - Form inspection

Tags: forms, element, dimensions, elm, inspection

The below function includes the use of `collage`, only to convert the
Shape/Form into an Element.

```
makeSlider : Element -> Form -> Element
makeSlider sliderShape sliderBarForm =
  let                                                                                                 
    sliderBar =
      --convert sliderBarForm from type Form to Element
      collage 1000 1000 [(move (0,0) sliderBarForm)]
  in 
    layers [sliderShape, sliderBar]
```

Is there a way to extract a Form's dimensions, like `Graphics.Element.sizeOf`, so that the `makeSlider` function does not need to know the explicit dimensions of `sliderBarForm`?

Or does a `toElement` function exist so that

`collage 1000 1000 [(move (0,0) sliderBarForm)]`

can be replaced with

`toElement (move (0,0) sliderBarForm)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can easily get the dimensions of a form.  I guess that's because a form can be so many different kinds of things (shapes, paths, etc). When I need to know the dimensions later, I keep track of them when I create the form.

```
type alias MyForm =
  {   form : Form
    , width : Int
    , height : Int
  }

makeRectForm: Float -> Float -> MyForm
makeRectForm  w h = {form: (filled grey (rect w h)), width: (round w), height: (round h)}
```

Then in your case you can use a `MyForm` with the `collage`.

```
makeSlider : Element -> MyForm -> Element
makeSlider sliderShape sliderBarMyForm =
  let                                                                                                 
    sliderBar =
      --convert sliderBarForm from type Form to Element
      collage sliderBarMyForm.width sliderBarMyForm.height [(move (0,0) sliderBarMyForm)]
  in 
    layers [sliderShape, sliderBar]
```

Comment: Makes sense - thanks - great, as I don't have to use extra parameters for `makeSlider`.